# SELECT tabA.*, tabB.* FROM ... => Duplicate Column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've got following tables:

| Supplier |
| --- |
| idSupplier |
| Name |

| Product |
| --- |
| idProduct |
| idSupplier |
| EAN |

Now I want to select all values from both tables. I'm using this Query:

```sql
SELECT
    Supplier.*,
    Product.*
FROM
    Supplier
        INNER JOIN
    Product
        ON Supplier.idSupplier = Product.idSupplier
```

The issue is, that MySQL/MariaDB complains about a duplicate column name. **I know, that you can eliminate the issue by listing all field separately and define a alias for the field `Product.idSupplier` or just by excluding it.**

But since I'm lazy and will probably forget, that this has to be expanded if I ever update or expand a table, I want a 'automatic' solution. This means, every newly added field should automatically be included in the result.

There are probably some MySQL magicians who can solve this.

Comment: Listing all fields in the select is generally how you handle this.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't complain about duplicate column names unless you wrap the query you show as a subquery.

If you can't give up your habit of using `SELECT *`, then you can solve it by making sure to define distinct column names in each table.

*Boom!* Problem solved. ️

But there's a problem in your original conditions:

> I'm lazy and will probably forget

Any solution we suggest can be circumvented by at least one of these.

Answer (score -1):

It's always better to explicitly specify the columns you want.

But in this particular case, you can join using `USING` instead of `ON` and doing a `SELECT *` instead of `tablename.*` to only get one copy of the column:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Supplier
        INNER JOIN
    Product
        USING(idSupplier)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It still returns duplicate columns when I test it on MySQL 8.0.29. It collapses the redundant column if you used `SELECT *`.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks, no I didn't actually try this query, I just tried select *.

Comment: (For the record I did not downvote. I hardly ever downvote any question or answer.)